# variable id might not have been initialized Spring Boot Controller with lombok

Tags: java

I am trying to add a simple controller method, but I am running into the following
`Exercise.java:[13,1] variable id might not have been initialized`

Here is the code that I am working with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exercises/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Exercise>> getExerciseById(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id) {
        Optional<Exercise> exercise = exerciseRepository.findById(id);
        if(id!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Exercise>>(exercise, HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Exercise>>(exercise, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

I am using an `Optional<Exercise>` here because I am taking advantage of the build in method `findById` from the `JpaRepository` package. I haven't found any good posts on how to handle this is. This is probably something simple. I've found some documentation around this:https://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-fix-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error-in-java.html, but I could use a little help understanding the best way to fix this. This is the exercise classe

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercise")
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Exercise {
    
    @Id
    @NonNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private int chapterId;

    private String exercise;

    private String answer;

    private String question;

    private String a;
    
    private String b;

    private String c;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you saying that `id` can be optional here?

Comment: Can you post the line of code that is giving the error? Ie, Exercise.java:[13,1]

Comment: That would be the line that initializes `exercise`

Comment: But what is the line in the Exercise.java file? It looks to me like the error is happening there and not in this controller...

Comment: Second thing is, you should return response on the basis of Optional returned from repository, not by checking `id`.

Comment: @xdhmoore I just updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I guess since you are using Lombok, the question is, what is the actual code running? I'm not sure how to find that, but you could probably at least find the method signature in the error stack trace, which would tell you if the error was happening in the generated Exercise constuctor or in a setter. My guess is it's the constructor.

Comment: @xdhmoore I narrowed it down to something within the way that I've configured the class.

Comment: Just a theory: maybe @ Value doesn't play well with @ NoArgsConstructor + jpa stuff, because JPA may try to use the no-args constructor and then set values using setters, but @ Value makes fields immutable (private & final), so changeable only in constructor. Not sure...

Comment: I would hazard a guess that if you swap @ Value with @ Data on the class that it will work

Comment: @xdhmoore that did indeed work.

Comment: Huzzah! Glad to hear it. I'd post an answer, but I'm not 100% what was going wrong. I think in general you may have to do something special to have immutable entities, like you would have using @ Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tldr;

I *don't think* JPA plays well with the immutable entity created by @Value. Use @Data instead.

### ihnbtdttrt (i have nothing better to do than to read this);

This partially guesswork, but since it has seemed to help, this is what I *think* is happening:

When you call `findById()`, JPA creates a new entity object using a no-argument constructor, and then sets the fields individually afterwards. (I'm not sure if it uses setters or sets the fields directly using reflection).

The @Value annotation, as documented [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value), makes a class immutable, with all the fields private and final and with no "setters" created. This means that the only way to set the fields is by passing the field values into a constructor with appropriate arguments. After that the fields are not changeable.

Since JPA initializes entities using the no-args constructor and tries to set the fields afterwards, with your setup, it uses the no-args constructor and ends up with an entity object where none of the fields have been initialized but none of them are modifiable after the constructor. All private, final fields, with no setters. Then it tries to call `entity.getId()`, and the `id` field hasn't been initialized, leading to the above error.

To fix this, you can use the `@Data` [annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) instead of `@Value`. This is similar, but doesn't create an immutable object. In particular, it generates "setter" functions and the fields are not set to final. This is the type of Java bean that JPA expects, one that can be initialized with a no-argument constructor and then have the fields set afterwards.

There may be ways to configure JPA to create objects differently, so that it passes all the data into a constructor so that you can have immutable entities. I know that some Spring DI stuff is configurable to initialize using rich constructors like this, but Idk about JPA.

For what it's worth, I appreciate the value of immutable objects for clean code, but it's not uncommon to find the above pattern of no-arg construction + post-construction setting when using the popular Java frameworks like JPA/Hibernate, Spring, etc. They don't always play well with immutability.